# Specific Viewing Privilege's in HTML and Python

Tags: python, html, django

I'm making a college events website for a project and one of the requirements is to be able to make events that are private for your student organization or your university. So all events should be tagged as either Public, Private(can only view if you attend the same university as the event creator), or RSO(can only view if you are in the same student organization as the event creator). I have managed to make a page where you can view all the events but I can't figure out how to make it so you can only view these events under the provided circumstances. Right now all the events no matter what the tag is show up for everyone looking at the events list page. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Python, You could try using the if else statement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).